# I am using python3. how can i switch to v2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, installation, pycharm

I tried downloading v2.7.x but it wasn't available. Almost all sites have updated to v3.x. If possible, please share the download link too.

- I am using the Pycharm IDE and current interpreter is v3.4.
- I want to shift to 2.7.1
- How do I add the 2.7 interpreter.

Comment: pyenv might be able to help

Comment: Official download link: (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/)

Comment: Think of it this way, python 2.7.1 is ancient. You should be installing it only if someone is pointing a gun to your head!

Comment: the latest version of 2.7 is 2.7.14

Comment: @avigii 
downloaded 7.14 and changed the interpreter. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the links here:

https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.1/

I was able to download.

Answer (score 0):

You can download python2.7 from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/) and install it. you can then call

> python2.7

on your terminal or cmd [after setting the env variable] to check if the installation was successful.

Comment: [2.7.14](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/) is actually the latest version

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the hyperlink for python 2.7.14

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to mange multiple versions of python. details about how to install can be find in the link above.

after installation you can simply install python 2.7 like this.

```
pyenv install 2.7.8
```

to install python 3.4

```
pyenv install 3.4.0
```

to make global python to 2.7.8 at any time

```
pyenv global 2.7.8
```